# Euclidean distance between two columns of two vector Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors `A & B` of size `250x4`. The first column in each vector has the X values and the second column has the Y values. I want to calculate the euclidean distance between each the `X & Y` of each row in the two vectors and save the result in a new vector C of size `250x1` which holds the result of the euclidean distance. For example, if the first row in `A` is `A1x, A1y, A1n, A1m` and the first row in `B` is `B1x, B1y, B1n, B1m` so I want to get the eucledian distance which will be [(A1x-B1x)^2 + (A1y-B1y)^2]^0.5 and the result will be saved in `C1` and same will be done for the rest of the 250 rows. So if anyone could please advise how to do this in Matlab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
%// First extract on x-y data from A and B
Axy = A(:,1:2);
Bxy = B(:,1:2); 
%// Find all euclidean distances (row-wise)
C1 = sqrt(sum((Axy-Bxy).^2,2));
```

plus it handles higher dimension too

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer to better suit the specifics of the question, i.e., using only the first tow columns of `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 1):

use `pdist2`:

```
C1=diag(pdist2(A(:,1:2),B(:,1:2)));
```

Actually, `pdist2` will give you a 250x250 matrix, because it calculate all the distances. You need only the main diagonal, so calling `diag` on the result (as in the code above) will produce the wanted result.

Comment: AAAA!!!! you are comuting ALL 250x250 possible distances in `pdist2` just to take the `diag` of the result! This is EXTREMELY inefficient. this is a bad use of Matlab's vectorization capabilities.

Comment: Practically 250*250 is peanuts, but actually you definitely right. (For computing terms, your solution is 2 ms, and mine is 3.5 ms...)

Comment: 1.5 ms is really not an issue here. It is a BAD practice to use off-the-shelf functions and use them without understanding the meaning of what they are doing. Performing O(n^2) computations instead of O(n) just becuase there's a `pdist2` function shows poor understanding of the tools one is using.